# Sort a HTML Table Numerically with Comma values

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

As we can see it's not working when there is Comma values

I am trying to sort a column of a HTML table containing comma values. I know how to sort values, but I am not sure how to sort the numbers having comma values.

In the below example, on page load, it has to sort by ascending order, but it's not sorting as expected. Please help me on this. Thank you so much in advance.

```js
function sortTable() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      //check if the two rows should switch place:
      if (Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)) {
        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="sortTable()">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>25000</td>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>75100</td>
    <td>North/South</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6550</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>88,000</td>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>69,500</td>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7500</td>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
</body>
```

As I mentioned, its working perfectly if it doesn't have commas, but the problem is the data is dynamic in nature as it is fetched from API and it will have the data having only comma values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Remove commas, change it into a `Number` and apply `Array#sort`.

```js
const nums = ["2,000", "1,000", "1,000,000", "3,500,000"];

nums.sort(
  (a, b) => Number(a.replaceAll(",", "")) - Number(b.replaceAll(",", ""))
);

console.log(nums);
```

#### In your solution just modify the following line:

`if (Number(x.innerHTML.replaceAll(",", "")) > Number(y.innerHTML.replaceAll(",", "")))`

```js
function sortTable() {
  const table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
  const rows = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll("tr")).slice(1);
  rows.sort(
    (a, b) =>
      Number(a.children[0].innerText.replaceAll(",", "")) -
      Number(b.children[0].innerText.replaceAll(",", ""))
  );
  table.innerHTML = rows.map((r) => `<tr>${r.innerHTML}</tr>`).join("");
}
```

```html
<body onload="sortTable()">
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>25000</td>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>75100</td>
      <td>North/South</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6550</td>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2000</td>
      <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88,000</td>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>69,500</td>
      <td>Paris specialites</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7500</td>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

#### Sorting the table rows using `Array#sort`.

```js
function sortTable() {
  const table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
  const rows = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll("tr")).slice(1);
  rows.sort(
    (a, b) =>
      Number(a.children[0].innerText.replaceAll(",", "")) -
      Number(b.children[0].innerText.replaceAll(",", ""))
  );
  table.innerHTML = rows.map((r) => `<tr>${r.innerHTML}</tr>`).join("");
}
```

```html
<body onload="sortTable()">

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>25000</td>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>75100</td>
      <td>North/South</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6550</td>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2000</td>
      <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88,000</td>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>69,500</td>
      <td>Paris specialites</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7500</td>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you soo much sir, finaly it helped me.

Comment: @Dannypath Welcome! I've added one more approach at the end, you can consider checking that out as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the comma in the value with nothing before converting it to `Number` (e.g. 10,000 becomes 10000).

Now for fun: let's simplify the sorting.

```js
document.body.onload = sortTable;

function sortTable() {
  const toNumber = value => +(value.replaceAll(/,/g, "")) || 0;
  //                              ^ the replacement here
  const firstCellTxt = row => row.cells[0].textContent;
  const sorter = (a, b) => toNumber(firstCellTxt(a)) - toNumber(firstCellTxt(b));

  // retrieve the current rows, convert to Array, slice to exclude <th>
  const originalRows = [...document.querySelectorAll(`#myTable tr`)].slice(1);
  const sorted = originalRows.slice() // clone original rows Array, 
    .map(row => row.cloneNode(true))  // clone every row
    .sort(sorter);                    // sort the clone using [sorter]

  // en passant convert the values to numbers in locale format
  // and replace the original rows with the sorted ones
  originalRows.forEach((el, i) => {
    sorted[i].cells[0].textContent =
      toNumber(firstCellTxt(sorted[i])).toLocaleString(`de-DE`);
    el.replaceWith(sorted[i]);
  });
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>25000</td>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>75100</td>
    <td>North/South</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6550</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>88,000</td>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>69,500</td>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7500</td>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: @Kooilnc Why are you replacing `,` with `.` and that too only the first one?

Comment: Because a number (float) can only have one decimal separator (`.`).

Comment: I don't think those are floats, looks more like thousand separator.

Comment: But wait, it's *thousands separators*? Ok, will edit the answer

Comment: I like the cloning and replacing thing, safer than using `innerHTML`.